# Rendering PDFs in ie inside the browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, iframe

I've looked at so many different SO posts about this today.

I have an application that needs to show PDF documents inside the browser. This application also needs to run in IE (11+).

Here's the thing: an `iframe` with a `src` works just fine. Something like:

```
<iframe src="www.myurl.com/thedocument"></iframe>
```

However, `www.myurl.com/thedocument` is now protected by oAuth. What this means is I need to request `www.myurl.com/thedocument` with the appropriate authorization header credentials.

This means (i think), that I have to request `www.myurl.com/thedocument` via ajax. The ajax request returns base64, or a byte[] containing the document.

IE doesn't support data URIs to render PDFs, so i can't just splat the response from my ajax request into the iframe.

So.. now I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), a javascript library for rendering PDFs into an HTML5 canvas with [support for IE10+](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#what-browsers-are-supported). The library supports loading PDF data from a TypedArray (e.g. Uint8Array), that could be produced from the result of an ajax request.

I've prepared a short example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwrage59/) that displays a single page PDF stored in a base64-encoded binary. To avoid performing the base64 conversion, a TypedArray could also be retrieved directly from an XMLHttpRequest response:

```
function reqListener () {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(this.response);
    PDFJS.getDocument(byteArray).then(function(page) {
        // ....
    });
}

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
req.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/example.pdf");
req.send();
```

To support the features that you would expect in a native pdf viewer (printing etc.) the library includes an [example viewer](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/) that you can adapt for your own purposes.

Comment: PDF.js is a great library. However, rendering ALL pages of the pdf at once is something the library doesn't do very good (where as rendering a data uri in chrome shows all the pages in the pdf - and it does it very well).

This is a great suggestion. Unfortunately, not it doesn't have the specific feature I'm looking for.

Comment: No problem. It wouldn't be the most performant way of rendering them, but for text-heavy documents it doesn't seem too bad. If you haven't already, you could try opening your pdfs in the [demo](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) to see whether it's up to scratch.

Comment: @Jeff With IE it is either PDF.js or iframe.  According to my research, given your situation you cannot use iframe, because IE does not support data uri iframe, so you don't have much choice here.